# Slowing down computer for debugging intermittent defect

Tags: performance, debugging, intermittent

Is there a way to slow down my development computer to try to replicate a defect that only occurs intermittently on a slow machine?

(For what it's worth, Ableton Live has a CPU usage simulation feature, but I've never seen something like this for debuggers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tool](http://www.playtool.com/pages/prime95/prime95.html) provides a decent CPU stress capability.  I assume that's what you mean by "slow down". :)

Answer (score 0):

> The currently popular stability test
>   programs are:
>
> - Prime95 (this program's torture test)
> - 3DMark2001
> - CPU Stability test
> - Sisoft sandra
> - Quake and other games
> - Folding@Home
> - Seti@home
> - Genome@home

This is from the stress testing documentation for Prime95.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I'd also suggest using VMWare Workstation. You can allocate more or less resources to virtual machines, and you can record/playback the execution of the machine, so you can catch the bug in the act and then step through it at your leisure.